# ifconfig don't work with cron

Tags: cron

I set up a cron job with this test script:

```
#!/bin/sh
date >> /media/log/crontest.txt
ifconfig tun0 >>/media/log/crontest.txt
```

And in this crontad -e

```
 */1 * * * * /media/config/pia/tmp
```

But I don't get the output for ifconfig in the crontest.txt:

```
Thu May 29 11:39:01 EST 2014
Thu May 29 11:40:01 EST 2014
Thu May 29 11:43:01 EST 2014
Thu May 29 11:44:02 EST 2014
Thu May 29 11:45:01 EST 2014
Thu May 29 11:46:01 EST 2014
Thu May 29 11:47:01 EST 2014
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cron scripts most likely lack `PATH` variable, therefore you have to specify the full path to your executables, that you could easily find using: `which ifconfig` and `which date`, and your script might look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
/bin/date >> /media/log/crontest.txt
/sbin/ifconfig tun0 >>/media/log/crontest.txt
```